# Detect Swipes in HTML application

Tags: jquery, html, css, web-applications, gesture

I'm making an application with Phone Gap that uses HTML, CSS and Javascript. I would like to capture a left or right swipe on a certain element that will bring up a menu, but I don't know how to capture such a gesture.

Looking around, people have suggested jQuery Mobile. I tried to use it but as soon as I added the jquery .js file my whole page layout broke, so it seems jquery is manipulating my layout somehow.

Is there any alternatives to jQuery, or is there somehow I can prevent jquery from destroying my whole web layout?

Comment: Google is your friend, http://www.queness.com/post/11755/11-multi-touch-and-touch-events-javascript-libraries. Jquery mobile has a lot of functionality that would clash with work you have setup. It's best to use it from the beginning rather than implement it into existing work. Check their API for understanding on what they do http://api.jquerymobile.com/

Comment: There a few different javascript libraries for detecting gestures on touch devices. Check out http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/ and http://quojs.tapquo.com/. They're easy to configure as well, e.g. you can set the length of time between taps to determine what registers as a double-tap, or the distance swiped (in pixels) to determine what's considered a swipe